# Object has been destroyed when open secondary/child window in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In a main window, when a button is clicked, the second/child window will popped up via an ipc call. 
This works when open the pop window on the first time. If I closed the pop window and reopen it again, I will get this error:

> Uncaught Exception: Error: Object has been destroyed at Error (native)
>   at EventEmitter. (/home/xxxx/electron/fin/main.js:36:21) at emitOne
>   (events.js:96:13) at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:188:7) at
>   EventEmitter.
>   (/home/xxxx/electron/fin/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/resources/electron.asar/browser/api/web-contents.js:156:13)
>   at emitTwo (events.js:106:13) at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)

```
#main.js on app ready:
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})


  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)


  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()


  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {

    mainWindow = null
  })

  let popWindow = new BrowserWindow({parent: mainWindow, width: 450, height: 450, show: false});
  popWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/pop.html`);
  popWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  ipc.on('toggle-popwindow', function(){
         popWindow.show();    
  });
```

And when I add hide() in the 'closed' method:

```
popWindow.on('closed', function (event) {
popWindow.hide();
});
```

I get this:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Object has been destroyed
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you close a browser window it will be destroyed, so you can't hide or show it again after that. Since you want to hide it and show it again later your should add a listener for the [`close` event](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v1.2.6/docs/api/browser-window.md#event-close) that calls `preventDefault()` and hides the window instead of closing it.

Answer (score 11):

when popWindow is closed,you should set popWindow to null. when the next open request from the ipc, instance popWindow again.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})


mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)


mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()


mainWindow.on('closed', function () {

  mainWindow = null
  popWindow=null;
})

ipc.on('toggle-popwindow', function(){
    if(!popWindow){
      openPopWindow(function(){
            popWindow.show();    
      });
    } else{
        popWindow.show();    
    }
});

function openPopWindow(callback){
  let popWindow = new BrowserWindow({parent: mainWindow, width: 450, height: 450, show: false});
    popWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/pop.html`);
    popWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  popWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function () {
    if (typeof callback == 'function') {
      callback();
    }
  });

    // set to null
  popWindow.on('close', () => {
    popWindow = null;
  });

    // set to null
  popWindow.on('closed', () => {
    popWindow = null;
  });
}
```